# Ruby on Rails image_tag not displaying the image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

In the gemfile I have installed carrierwave to allow a user to upload a profile image. I sort of followed the instructions in this railscast - http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

```
gem 'carrierwave'
```

However image is not displaying with image_tag. I can see the image directory by testing it without the image_tag. I also navigated in the image directory to ensure that image is stored. I can see it in the director "/uploads/user/image/110/"

[image]

In the view it shows the image url **"/uploads/user/image/110/thumb_IMG_0017.JPG"**

```
<%= @user.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

**Adding an image tag displays nothing**

```
<%= image_tag @user.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

**ImageUploader**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  #include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end


end
```

**Controller**

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    ...
end

private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :image)
    end
```

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    ...
end
```

Querying the database directly for example for user 110 displays the following

```
User.find(110).image_url(:thumb)
User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 110]]
 => "/uploads/user/image/110/thumb_IMG_0017.JPG"
```

Comment: Any errors / logs you can report back with?

Comment: The image just comes back with 404 or something? what happens on the page itself?

Comment: Ok I tried doing this - http://localhost:3000/uploads/user/image/110/thumb_IMG_0017.JPG. I get No route matches [GET] "/uploads/user/image/110/thumb_IMG_0017.JPG"

Comment: Do you have the `uploads` folder in your `/public` directory?

Comment: uploads folder is under the public folder directory. Am I meant to do this http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/user/image/110/thumb_IMG_0017.JPGI still get the same route matches get error

Comment: Hmmmm - have you tried restarting like @marflar suggests?

Comment: does it work without the resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I checked the server logs

```
Checked the server log looks like a routing issue - Started GET "/uploads/user/image/111/thumb_IMG_1355.JPG" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-12 11:00:29 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/user/image/111/thumb_IMG_1355.JPG"):
```

It looks like the issue will get fix by going into config/environments/production.rb and development.rb and setting the following to true!

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: Are you in production mode? That will affect things. Are you on heroku or something?

Comment: Production is heroku. Right now I'm in my local development machine.

Comment: Just a heads up here... DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and
 is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to restart your server after setting carrierwave up. That will fix everything.

Comment: I restarted it, it didn't fix the problem. Do I need the public folder in the route?